# "at the fringes of the haute intelligentsia"

Tags: meaning

*His milieu was one of great social and cultural privilege. Wassily Kandinsky was his uncle, and the entire family **circulated at the fringes of the haute intelligentsia**.*

This passage is supposed to show that the man came from the high society. But in my opinion the phrase "the entire family circulated at the fringes of the haute intelligentsia" doubts this assertions. The phrase has for me a negative connotation. To be at the fringes means after all not to belong to the center, to be somewhat out. How do you interpret the passage? Does it contradict the first part of the clause or confirm it?

Comment: The ***haute** intelligentsia* is a relatively rare term more likely to occur in French than English texts. But since it means the *very upper echelons* of the [intelligentsia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligentsia), who are already defined as the *artistic, social, or political **vanguard** or **elite***, the implication is that this family are not only part of that elite - they're close to being part of the much smaller "super-elite". It's like the difference between being a member of the ***nobility*** (pretty high up), or being right at the top - ***royalty***.

Comment: His family was itself not directly a part of the core of intellectuals but they did find themselves in the company of those intellectuals because of the intellectual status of their relatives.

Comment: [The Haute intelligentsia - four thousand people at the most (the Soviet Union lists thirty million officially as their intelligentsia) - is extremely reticent not only about its power but even about its existence.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nknwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22the+haute+intelligentsia%E2%80%9D&dq=%22the+haute+intelligentsia%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Obviously, the author must've felt that mixing *three* languages instead of just two made the phrase sound that much more pretentious, um, I mean, prestigious. :)

Answer (score 6):

FumbleFingers' comment is correct, but it's also important to note that the intelligentsia are specifically **intellectuals**, it is not a general term for the social elite. It's possible to be part of high society without being part of the intelligentsia.

Comment: +1. And not merely possible but probable.